# Lightdm doesn't load on boot

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, lightdm, radeon

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and since yesterday lightdm doesn't load on boot.

Ubuntu loads normally but there is no UI just this cursor _  blinking.
I tried in console(Ctrl + Alt + F4):`sudo service lightdm start`&`sudo start lightdm`  nothing happens.
Then I realized that X11 wont start and I reinstalled it and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What graphics chipset/card ?

Comment: AMD e2-2000 APU with radeon hd 7340.

Comment: Start with: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: And does ´startx´ work?

Comment: No, it says "Fatal server error: no screens found"

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a TTY and type `sudo pkill X` that might work (it does anyways).  Still looking for a fix, though.